# Is Array.prototype.map.bind reliable to use with objects?

Tags: javascript

I like the Array.prototype.map method, and some time ago I came across a use of it I didn't expect.

```
    var xargByID = { a: 1, b: 2 };

    Array.prototype.map.bind(xargByID)(function (xarg) {

    });
```

I don't know how Array.prototype.map internally works so I have to ask, is it reliable? Might it break with time?

Answer (score 2):

It simply not works. You can call `Array.map` only on Objects that have numerical properties starting with 0 and have a corresponding length property. So only this will work:

```
var xargByID = {0: 'first', 1: 'second', 2: 'third', length: 3};

Array.prototype.map.bind(xargByID)(function (xarg) {
    console.log(xarg);
});
```

It's because `.map()` internally does something like the following simulation:

```
function simulateMap(callback, thisArg) {
    var ret = [], length = this.length, that = thisArg || this;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ret.push(callback.call(that, this[i], i, this));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It's the same with `.forEach()`, `.some()`, and so on.

**EDIT** But if you like `.map()` so much you can do:

```
var xargByID = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(xargByID).map(function(xarg, i, arr) {
    console.log(xarg, arr[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `.bind` is definitely not the best way to write your example, much better would be `Array.prototype.map.call(xargByID, function (xarg) {`.

It will work as long as the object is array-like: it has a `length` property that is an integer >= 0, and the elements you want to iterate over are at properties that integers >= 0 and < the length. This is not a hack, it is by design; `Array.prototype.map` is made to be usable on non-`Array` objects, as long as they have that `Array`-like form.

In your example, it would not work, because the properties are not at numeric indexes and there is no length property. But it would work if xArgByID were, for example, this: `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', length: 2}`.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this doesn't answer the reliability aspect of your question, but if you have access to a library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/) then you can use its [map function](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to iterate over an object. This ***is*** reliable.

> _.map(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])
>
> Creates an array of values by running each element in collection through iteratee. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments:
> (value, index|key, collection).

Depending on exactly what you want to do you may also want to consider the `_.forOwn()`, `_.forIn()` and `_.forEach()` methods. They also iterate over properties in an Object.

EDIT: As per cortopy's comment below I've updated this answer to be accurate for lodash 4.x. (The previous answer was accurate for lodash 3.x)

Comment: Which version of lodash? 4.6.1. doesn't accept a thisArg. I think you may be confusing it with the native Array.prototype.map() which does support a [thisArg] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @cortopy Yes this changed in lodash 4.x. I've updated the answer.